# Automating Gzip enabling and caching expiration in Apache

Tags: drivers, apache2, lamp, cache, gzip

Instead me having to copy-paste the following codes to enable Gzip comperssing and cache expiration into my `apache2.conf` each time I create a new server-environment, is there a way to make them appear there from Apache itself with some CLI commands maybe?

```
## ENABLE GZIP
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
## ENABLE GZIP ##

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

### Update

Is there no other way to add these to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` automatically without pasting or `include`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy your configuration as easy as possible, the best way is to run a script (or run each of the commands).

You don't need all the changes you listed. Apache2 already comes with `mods-available/deflate.conf` similar to yours. Just enable it to get the GZIP support.

The script would be (I called it `a2gzip.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > /etc/apache2/mods-available/expires.conf << EOF
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
        ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
        ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
EOF

a2enmod deflate expires
systemctl reload apache2
```

Use `sudo ./a2gzip.sh` to run the script.

Comment: Thx, why didn't you appended the heredocument content into the end of `apache2.conf` instead?

Comment: The result is the same if you put everything in `apache2.conf`. But keeping the settings separated in each module, makes the management and debug easier.

You can enable or disable compression just by doing `a2enmod deflate` or `a2dismod deflate`. The same for the settings related to `expire`. If you have some user complaining about cached resources, you can debug the problem by just `a2dismod expires` and then `a2enmod expires` again without changing other apache settings.

Comment: Hmm, please allow me one more question, must we add all the list of cache-expiration directives as well? Shouldn't `a2enmod expires` be enough in 2018 to Google's guidelines?

Comment: I mean, shouldn't the default directives be enough?